# How to list empty files? (Bash)

Tags: bash, performance, file, awk, find

In order to list empty files I do

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs wc -l | awk -F" " '{if ($1==0) {print $2} }'
```

or simply

```
wc -l *.txt | awk -F" " '{if ($1==0) {print $2} }'
```

It works but it is a bit slow as `wc -l` counts the number of newline characters in each file while this is not necessary. A process that excludes files as soon as they find a single newline character would be much faster.

**How can one list empty files in a performant way?**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.txt' -size 0
```

Print files which match `*.txt` and are of size zero.

Comment: `-size 0c` might be more efficient, for some vanishingly small value of "more".  (`find` doesn't need to first divide the file size by 512 and round the result up.)

Answer (score 13):

To find all empty files in the current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -empty
```

How it works:

- `find .`

  This starts `find` looking for files in the current directory.
- `-maxdepth 1`

  By default, `find` searches recursively through subdirectories.  This tells it not to.  If you do want a recursive search, just remove this option.
- `-type f`

  This limits the search to regular files.
- `-name '*.txt'`

  This limits the search to `.txt` files.
- `-empty`

  This limits the search to empty files.

Comment: Why the `-maxdepth` stuff?  The question doesn't mention limiting it to the current directory, does it?  The filtering stuff doesn't eliminate files from sub-directories either, AFAICS.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler One of the examples in the question was `wc -l *.txt` which limits the search to the current directory.  Removing `maxdepth` provides, of course, the recursive solution.

Comment: OK, fair enough — the primary example didn't use that limit.  It was a minor quibble.  Using `-empty` instead of `-size 0` is a (GNU `find`) extension compared with POSIX [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), though Mac OS X (BSD) `find` also supports it.  I think they're separate implementations — the Mac OS X version does not respond to `find --version` but the GNU version does.

Comment: Can `-empty` able to find files only have new-line in it?

Comment: @alper No, `-empty` only finds files of zero-size.

Answer (score 0):

Non-recursive with `stat`, output control with `awk`:

`$ stat -c "%n %b" *|awk '!$2 && $0=$1'`

`stat` prints filename (`%n`) and allocated block count (`%b`). In `awk` refrain from printing if blocks allocated (`!$2`) and replace record with filename when printing.